# Accessing items of a bean object

Tags: php, orm, redbean

i'm using redbeanphp like this

```
$r = R::find('chat', 'room_id = ? AND time > ? ORDER BY time ASC', array($w->id, $_POST['latest_timestamp']));
```

Now i a have a list of bean objects inside $r so is there any way to access rows without convert it to array?

(i know i can't use it with foreach !)

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($r);`?

Comment: found the problem is should use findAll ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here http://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/finding_beans

`R::find` is to load a single entry, shouldn't you be using `R:findAll` to get an array collection that you can iterate via `foreach`?

i.e.

```
$r = R::findAll('chat', 'room_id = ? AND time > ? ORDER BY time ASC', array($w->id, $_POST['latest_timestamp']));

foreach ($r as $myItem)
{
    // do something with $myItem
}
```